# compiling java program with multiple .jar files (mac)

Tags: java, macos, jar, command-line-arguments

I am currently trying to write a program that reads the metadata of images using the library from here: https://github.com/drewnoakes/metadata-extractor/wiki/GettingStarted. My issue is that I cannot figure out how to compile the program using more than one .jar file (and it requires two). Both jar files are in my working directory, with the java file I'm trying to compile.

This is the command I am using, with just one .jar file referenced. 
 javac -cp metadata-extractor-2.7.2.jar MetadataPhotoExtractor.java

Thanks for any help 
-Aaron

Comment: separate then with `:` on Mac/Unix/Linux and `;` on Windows after the `-cp`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use colon on unix-like systems as separator.

```
javac -cp metadata-extractor-2.7.2.jar:my-other-jar.jar MetadataPhotoExtractor.java
```

On Windows use semicolons because the colon is restricted for drive letter separation.

Answer (score 3):

for windows

```
javac -cp metadata-extractor-2.7.2.jar;myother.jar  MetadataPhotoExtractor.java
```

for Linux

```
javac -cp metadata-extractor-2.7.2.jar:myother.jar  MetadataPhotoExtractor.java
```

Answer (score 2):

More arguments are accountet as a list separated with : of the current parameter.

`javac -cp lib1.jar:lib2.jar:lib3.jar myClass.java`

Have you tried:

`javac -cp metadata-extractor-2.7.2.jar:xmpcore-5.1.2.jar MetadataPhotoExtractor.java`